# CPU's for LGA775 Socket - advice needed

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, processor-socket

Hiya I forgot if this is the right site for "processors and hardware etc" but I need some opinion on this and advice...

On my current PC,

- Intel Celeron 440 @ 2.0Ghz
- 1 GB DDR2
- Motherboard is G31M-GS R2.01
- PSU = ACE 350X (Maximum Output 350Watts)

Now I am looking to upgrade it, so it's at least... usable. I am thinking of putting a Intel Core 2 Duo E8600, is this a wise choice and if yes what changes will have to do? Will I have to change the PSU or etc.

Also I will also be upgrading the RAM to the max (8GB).

Comment: Your going to spend more money on ancient hardware (over a decade old) then you would on the cheapest budget pc.  If you do the upgrade be sure to upgrade your firmware before you attempt booting with the new CPU

Comment: Yeah, Ik it's pretty ancient, just as a project I'm trying to see what I can do.

Comment: This not the right site for hardware shopping recommendations. Also, you're asking an opinion question: "Is this a wise choice". The answer to most people would be "no, it's not a wise choice" for the reasons @Ramhound mentioned above. You may have specific reasons we do not know why this may be a wise choice for you, and we cannot know that for you, hence this being an opinion-based question.

Comment: @TheGreatScorpio The hardware you listed is supported by your motherboard.  Outside of that sentence, it's unlikely, we can help you with this particular question

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean... you can't really do that much with it. I mean, I'm not gonna try make it into an ultimate gaming PC XD, just as something that I can use as a backup or something. It's just a project not something too serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the right place for hardware recommendations, but I'm going to answer this because I think it's unfair to automatically throw out hardware based on age and build a new machine in every scenario. That's not to say you should keep old machines forever; it depends on the workload. This is that part that will attract opinionated answers as if it's worth upgrading or just starting anew; I'm going to answer the question from a fairly simple standpoint because of that: what you can do, not if you should. I'd say because of the extremely low marginal cost, it might be worth it. But that's my opinion.

[Your motherboard supports up through the highest Core 2 Quads](http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/g31m-gs%20r2.0/#CPU); this should provide a much needed bump in CPU performance. Cheap C2Qs like the Q6600 [can be found for under $10](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_sop=15&_nkw=q6600&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1), and 771 Xeons are often even cheaper while overclocking better and can be used with many 775 motherboards with [some modification](http://www.delidded.com/lga-771-to-775-adapter/). They won't compete even clock-for-clock with modern processors because of IPC improvements, but [they can still tow their weight in games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUqBW-kq1_0), and will be plenty fine in light productivity. Depending, add a GPU of reasonable caliber (I wouldn't go above a GTX 1050/RX 460.)

Get [4-8GB of DDR2 depending on your needs.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5KBvnKiTqU&list=LLm5Pi7SbyjnqdrdO-JFqPWg&index=22) Just productivity? 4GB is probably fine. Gaming? 8GB maybe what you want. Note for the latter you'll need 4GB sticks because your motherboard only has two slots. The biggest challenge here will be finding 4GB sticks of DDR2; while there's plenty of ECC DDR2 in that size, finding desktop memory in that size may be quite a challenge.

Good luck in your ventures.